# JSF frontend calling C++ event handler client functions

Tags: c++, jsf, c++builder

I have a huge code written in C++. The code has around 300 screens.
I want the new screens to be written in JSF.

However, rewriting the the existing C++ code is a lot of work.

Is there a way to create a generic code to interact between HTML/JSF components and C++ components?

My problem is that I feel that C++ components are not parallel to JSF components. Am I write about it?

Is there a solution?

**EDITED**

Our components are VCL - Delphi for C++

Comment: Since our components are VCL (delphi for C++)

Comment: Then you'd better add a tag for C++ Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no 'automatic' way or tool to create JSF screens from Delphi / C++Builder forms.

If the code base follows a clean model/view/controller architecture, maybe with some effort the C++ side can be extended by a service layer, which could be accessed from the Java side using JNA, web services, a message-oriented middleware or other interprocess communication methods.